# Integration with SAP

Tags: c#, parameters, null, integration, saprfc

I am creating a system to integrate with SAP.

The client gave me the function and parameters, according to him, this function was usually performed in SAP but in my code when I try to retrieve the parameter, it returns me null.

Here's my code (EDIT: based on the RFC client provided within SAP GUI for Windows):

```
SAPFunctionsOCX.SAPFunctionsClass func = new SAPFunctionsOCX.SAPFunctionsClass();
func.Connection = connection;
SAPFunctionsOCX.IFunction ifunc = (SAPFunctionsOCX.IFunction)func.Add(functionName);
SAPTableFactoryCtrl.Tables tables = (SAPTableFactoryCtrl.Tables)ifunc.Tables;
SAPTableFactoryCtrl.Table objTable = (SAPTableFactoryCtrl.Table)tables[tableName];
    
//Paramters (Find one column "MATNR"
SAPTableFactoryCtrl.Columns cols2 = (SAPTableFactoryCtrl.Columns)objTable.Columns;
for (int i = 1; i <= cols2.Count; i++)
{
    SAPTableFactoryCtrl.Column col = (SAPTableFactoryCtrl.Column)cols2[i];
    Console.WriteLine(col.Name);
}
    
//Error here!  matnr == null
SAPFunctionsOCX.IParameter matnr = (SAPFunctionsOCX.IParameter)ifunc.get_Exports("MATNR");
```

Searching the internet found several examples similar to mine,
[here](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1425169), [here](http://sunhongwei2002.blog.163.com/blog/static/149007012201062165717737/) and [here](http://blog.csdn.net/robaot/archive/2009/10/20/4704127.aspx)!

**Why the method `get_Exports("MATNR");` returns null?**

Comment: is this a standard function module? I can't see it in the code. The export parameter list could be null, maybe there are table parameters you need to check instead.

Comment: functionName, tableName are variable containing the name of the function and table name respectively.

Table parameters can not recover, there is a method get_Exports and function. (See examples on [here](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1425169), [here](http://sunhongwei2002.blog.163.com/blog/static/149007012201062165717737/) and [here](http://blog.csdn.net/robaot/archive/2009/10/20/4704127.aspx)

Comment: I dont think example 3 is correct. Normally you assign import parameters not export parameters.

Comment: Actually I tried the method get_Imports too, but he also returned null

Answer (score 1):

What are the exact parameters that where given to you for the RFC function  ?
In the first part you seems to be looping over the column name of a table, and in the second one, you're searching for a parameter (ie not in the table).

regards
Guillaume

PS : ABAP is SAP proprietary language

Comment: The loop was just to list the names of the columns. It is of no use beyond this.

The parameter you want to retrieve is the "MATNR"

Comment: is MATNR a field of the table ? as i said, you're trying to get a parameters. Without the technical description of the function, there is not much we can do. Is this a standard function or a specific one (in which case it will begin by 'Z' or 'Y') ?

Comment: function begins with "y " (I'll get the full name of the function is comment here)
MATNR is a field.

Comment: **Function name is:** YYPCL_RFC_ESTOQUES. **Paramter is:** MATNR

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the actual function call, at least in the code sample

Comment: I'm not sure. If the example links are right, he's trying to get the parameter to fill it before the call...

Comment: I can not call the function without passing the parameter before because otherwise it will bring all the records (no filter).

Comment: why are you trying to access the export parameter list? It wont hold any values until the function module is executed

Comment: because I need to pass a parameter to the function to be able to filter the results.  

I'm just following the examples listed above

Comment: that's bugging me also... normally you get the "import" parameters, fill them, execute and get the export parameters. In you code and the exemples, you're filling an export. Perhaps this is a "Modification" param. That's why we're asking for the function definition

Comment: **Function name is:** YYPCL_RFC_ESTOQUES. **Paramter is:** MATNR

Comment: Searching the internet I saw a VB6 way to pass parameter. But an error occurs. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Riderman/amBub/) is my code in C #.
**Error:** Parameter not optional DISP_E_PARAMNOTOPTIONAL. **Full Error:** System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8002000F): Parameter not optional. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000F (DISP_E_PARAMNOTOPTIONAL))
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at SAPTableFactoryCtrl._CSAPTaFacRow.set_Cell(Int32 lRow, Object vaColumn, Object )